# sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, redhat, sudo

I moved the file /etc/sudoers to /etc/sudoers.bkp
after this I cannot run sudo command and neither can login as root and change the file back
is there any way this can be resolved without reinstalling the system

Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.4 (Ootpa)

Please suggest

Comment: Stop the system, boot on USB key, mount your official system and move the file to the right place. The reboot without key

Answer (score 1):

You can start the emergency mode and then change the name of the file

Bootup into Emergency mode(target)

1. During bootup, when the GRUB2 menu shows up, press the e key for edit.
2. Add the following parameter at the end of the linux16 line :

`systemd.unit=emergency.target`

3. Press Ctrl+x to boot the system with the parameter.

OR

1. Method 1
   There is a GRUB2 menu option when you boot up the system which can be selected to directly boot into rescue mode.
2. Method 2
3. During bootup, when the GRUB2 menu shows up, press the e key for edit.
4. Add the following parameter at the end of the linux16 line:

`systemd.unit=rescue.target`

3. Press Ctrl+x to boot the system with the parameter

Try this and rename the file, if you want to backup never use the command `mv`, now your learn in a tough way is better use the command `cp`. The `mv` command rename a file when we use the same `dir` and move the file into a new location if you specify this new location

Good luck pal

Comment: This is done in a Ec2 instance so I am not sure if boot time steps can be done.

Comment: Here are [the instructions to do this on an EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/using-ec2-serial-console-to-access-the-grub-menu-and-recover-from-boot-failures/) - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The issue caused by mistake
instead of

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

the last line was modified into

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers
```